# The add method has already created within the base class. How do I call it from a child class with putting values

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class A:
    def add(self,a,b):
      return (a+b)
class B(A):
    def result(self):
        print("The result is: ",self)
a=A()
a.add(10,20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `self.add()` from the method in the child class.

```
class A:
    def add(self,a,b):
      return (a+b)
class B(A):
    def result(self):
        x = int(input("First number:"))
        y = int(input("Second number:"))
        print("The result is: ",self.add(x, y))
b=B()
b.result()
```